is there any difference between past simple and perfect

I thought you were good looking

I thought you had been good looking

I thought you broke your leg

I thought you had broken your leg


Am I right that 1 means that at that time I had knowledge that at that time she was good looking and 2 that at that time I had knowledge that at a time prior to that time she was good looking.
On the other  hand 3 and 4 mean the same thing. Yet, during the test I think it is better to choose 4 since the original sentence in the present tense would sound like "I think you broke your leg" not "I think you break your leg". Correct?

Re the original sentence in the present tense would sound like "I think you broke your leg" not "I think you break your leg," the answer is no - your reasoning is not correct. Q: "What do you think happens if you fall off the stage?" A: "I think you break your leg".

This question is similar to: Backshifting: past simple to past perfect. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Best to use "Had broken your leg" in special cases alone, when placing the break earlier than another event also in the past.

@YosefBaskin - Not in my English.  I would use (4) to mean "I was under the impression that you were suffering from the effects of a broken leg".

Such sentences can mean many different things.
